# Is SL4A Project Active?

Tags: android, sl4a

Is the project **Scripting Layer for Android (SL4A)** actively developed or used for applications these days?

If not what are the alternatives available for scripting (Python) on android?

It appears to be some what obsolete, no update since 2012.

https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/downloads/list

Answer (score 3):

Yes, numerous people have forked the project and are maintaining on github.

https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a

https://github.com/ainsophical/DROID_PYTHON

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Qpython app on the play market, they have an sl4a libs + kivy and also a pip installer. [play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus)