# How to embed a Python interpreter in an Android App

Tags: python, android

I'd like to execute python code from an Android app. I wish to implement a text editor in my app where the user can load, edit and run his script. I will create specific functions for the user to code some functionality into the app. For now, I've identified Python as the most friendly language for my purpose.

**What methods are there for creating an embedded python interpreter in an android app?** I've been looking at Kivy framework, and was maybe hoping that I could use the python command `exec(codeString)` to run the code. But Kivy is packaged by Buildozer tool to produce an *.apk for android, which might be compiled and not interpreted. Would this work?

There are several apps out there that allow python coding in an Android device, so technically it is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is SL4A Project Active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588514/is-sl4a-project-active)

Comment: have you tried building executables (arm, arm64, x86, x86_64) out of your python runtime loading code using nuitka and invoking (eval) python scripts with it?

Comment: I am also exploring this topic and this one https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/ looks promising to integrate python code into android app.